# React - Can't find modules after moving folder structure

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

Looking for a quick answer.

I've moved my scss and fonts folders from src/ to src/assets and I'm getting the below error:

[image]

The code in this folder is as below:

```
src:  url('~assets/fonts/icomoon.eot?q72v19');
```

I was like what... that is right! I've been scratching my head and though find I'll put my fonts folder back out of the assets folder so src/fonts.

And changed the code above to:

```
 src:  url('~fonts/icomoon.eot?q72v19');
```

Now I get the exact same message but for this path. So my original folder structure before I moved it into assets now doesn't work. And I'm stuck with a error.

I should point out that this is using create-react-app and I have ejected so I had more control over the webpack configs.

This is my folder structure I'm currently trying to make work:

[image]

I'm hoping this will be an easy fix as I'm wasting time on this..

Answer (score 0):

**How I Solved**: Stopped the server then restarted and edited paths with errors.
In terminal

1. **Press** `Ctrl+C` ,
2. then `Y`
3. then `npm start`
4. then `Edit Paths`
   (pointing to new directory of moved files/folder)

Answer (score -1):

Quick answer, delete everything and start from a fresh clone.